# uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

i'm trying to make one menu in my app that show one link for each categorie of my Places model.

i make it happen but only works in the first time i visit my app, after that i get this error

**NameError in Application#index**

**uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::Category**

```
Extracted source (around line #9):
7
8
9
10
11
12

    @places = Place.all
    @states = State.all
    @categories = ActsAsTaggableOn::Category.all


  end
```

If i restart my rails server my menu works for the fisrt time again, that get error.

My ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def index
    @places = Place.all
    @states = State.all
    @categories = ActsAsTaggableOn::Category.all
  end
end
```

My Places

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name , :state, :city, :neighborhood, :adress,:latitude, :longitude
  belongs_to :user

  acts_as_ordered_taggable_on :categories, :obstacles
end
```

Index.erb menu code

```
    <% categories.each do |category| %>  

    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i><%= category.name%>      <span>32</span></a></li>

   <%end %>
```

Comment: Please don't edit the basic premise of your question away. Also, instead of editing a question's title, please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217589) which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `@categories = ActsAsTaggableOn::Category.all`, you ned to fo following:

```
    @categories = @places.map(&:categories)
```

Comment: Omg, i was so stupid haha, **@categories = Category.all** and everything goes right ^^ , thanks for your help

Comment: @user1684409: Accept the answer, so that this question is closed.